# Android pass values to class

Tags: android, database, class, view

I want to pass the data obtained by this method, which is located in a fragment, to a class that extends a View (this class is in a library project associated to my project).

Method in a fragment

```
 public void checkOperatori(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String OPERATORI = "SELECT DISTINCT(nome), cognome FROM Operatori";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(OPERATORI, null);
    int count = cur.getCount();
    String[] nome_op = new String[count];
    String[] cognome_op = new String[count];
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        cur.moveToNext();
        nome_op[i] = cur.getString(0);
        cognome_op[i] = cur.getString(1);
        mWeekView.setData(nome_op[i], cognome_op[i]);
    }


     cur.close();
     db.close();

}
```

Class that extends a View

```
public class WeekView extends View {
public void setData(String nome_op[], String cognome_op[])
{
    this.nome_op = nome_op[];
    this.cognome_op = cognome_op[];
}
public String get_nome_op()
{
    return nome_op;
}
public String get_cognome_op()
{
    return cognome_op;
}
}
```

Comment: btw, why are you reaching database directly? You should be using api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make getter/setter methods inside your WeekView class?

```
public class WeekView extends View {
    ...
    private String nome_op, cognome_op;
    public void setData(String nome_op, String cognome_op)
    {
        this.nome_op = nome_op;
        this.cognome_op = cognome_op
    }
    public String get_nome_op()
    {
        return nome_op;
    }
    public String get_cognome_op()
    {
        return cognome_op;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
...
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String nome_op = cur.getString(0);
    String cognome_op = cur.getString(1);
    YOURWEEKVIEW.setData(nome_op, cognome_op);
    }
...
```

EDIT:

```
public void setData(String[] nome_op, String[] cognome_op)
{
    this.nome_op = nome_op;
    this.cognome_op = cognome_op;
}
public String[] get_nome_op()
{
    return nome_op;
}
public String[] get_cognome_op()
{
    return cognome_op;
}
```

Comment: make it static then, if you want.

Comment: I edited my post, because I want to pass 2 arrays. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: `this.nome_op = nome_op;
        this.cognome_op = cognome_op;` **incompatible types**

Comment: @JJkk change your `private String nome_op, cognome_op;` to `private String[] nome_op, cognome_op;`

Comment: we're almost done, however this line? `mWeekView.setData(nome_op[i], cognome_op[i]);`

Comment: `mWeekView.setData(nome_op, cognome_op);`. At least upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling a function using the Class name and not the object of this class.. Like:

```
WeekView.setData(nome_op, cognome_op);
```

You need to instantiate a variable

```
WeekView weekView = new WeekView();
weekView.set(nome_op, cognome_op);
```

If you want to call a method without create a object of this class, you need to set the method like *static*

```
public static String getSomething();
```

Comment: I edited my post, because I want to pass 2 arrays. Can you help me? Thank you